# Hide "0" values of a column until event using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm working with a large table. Right now when the user inputs quantity and price values, the total value is calculated and displayed in a column. However, when the first result is calculated, each cell in the Total Value column is populated with "0.00". How can I hide the default value of each row until the result is calculated? I'm relatively new to jQuery.

```
function calculate() {
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    var tbl = $(document.getElementById('21.125-mrss-cont-none-content'));
    tbl.find('tr').each(function () {
        $(this).find("input[name$='9#if'], input[name$='7#if']").bind("keyup", function () {
            calculateProduct();
            autoNum();
        });
    });

    function calculateProduct() {
        var tbl = $(document.getElementById('21.125-mrss-cont-none-content'));
        tbl.find('tr').each(function () {
            var product = $(this).find("input[name$='7#if']").val() * $(this).find("input[name$='9#if']").val();
            $(this).find("input[name$='9#if'], input[name$='7#if']").each(function () {
                if (!isNaN(this.value) && this.value.length != 0) {
                    parseFloat(product);
                }
            });
            $(this).find('.total').val(product.toFixed(2));
        });
    }
```

[image]

Comment: An aside: `parseFloat(product);` on its own does nothing, because you are ignoring its return value. Thus, you can do away with the entire call to `jQuery#each` surrounding it (5 lines of code).

Comment: Why don't you set the total to a blank value if there is no quantity or price?

Comment: I wrote a simple if else statement and it worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is, set the default value of the total column as blank (""). Then, when you actually have some data to show, just write that data into that column.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the blank before calculating the value.. So it will be like: all the column is blanked since you don't calculate the value.. Maybe in "autoNum()" you can set all the blanks.. But that must be do before starting "calculateProduct()". Hope this answare can be useful